# Operating system MINGW64_NT-10.0-19045 is not supported by this installation script error

Tags: base-de-datos, bash

Estaba intentando instalar el cli de turso y al tirar esta linea de comando en bash me sale este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ponte en contacto con servicio al cliente y/o revisa la documentación de dicho CLI para ver si cumples con los requisitos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Pues aparentemente estas intentando instalar un programa solo para Linux, en Windows 10. Yo probaría instalarlo en una VM de Linux